# Basis for a vector space consisting of the set of linear combinations of these functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

S is the vector space consisting of the set of all linear combinations of the functions $f_1(x)=e^x$, $f_2(x)=e^{-x}$, $f_3=sinh(x)$. Find a basis for S and find the dim[S].

First, I let

$c_1f_1$+$c_2f_2$+$c_3f_3$=$f$

Then, since $sinh(x) =\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$,

$f_3=\frac{f_1-f_2}{2}$

Substituting back in, I can get

$c_1f_1$+$c_2f_2$+$c_3\frac{f_1-f_2}{2}$ =$f$

$(c_1+\frac{1}{2}c_3)f_1$+$(c_2-\frac{1}{2}c_3)f_2$ =$f$

Am I on to something?

Comment: Nice name, by the way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup! :) You are correct. You have shown that $f_3$ is a linear combination of the other two basis vectors, and thus not needed to form the basis of the vector space (although you could have just as easily proved any *one* of the three given functions wasn't needed). As a result, since you have two basis functions, your subspace dimension is 2.

Answer (score 2):

$f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent and, as you point out, $f_3$ is dependent on these two, so a basis is $B=\{f_1,f_2\}$ and the dimension is 2.

Comment: I hate deciding who to "accept an answer" from..... You answered first, but FundThmCalculus provided more insight.... I feel bad haha

Answer (score 1):

$f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent (check using the definition), while $f_3$ is a linear combination of the first two. So the basis (i.e. linearly independent set which spans the space) is just $\{f_1,f_2\}$. Since this set contains two elements, the space is two dimensional.